# Solving JPA query finding the last entry in connected list

Tags: java, jpa, dao

Following class structure is given:

```
class Job 
{
    String description;
    Collection<JobHistory> history;
}

class JobHistory
{
    Date assignDate;
    User jobOwner;
}

class JobOwner 
{
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

This class-structure is accessible on the db via JPA. In the DAO-Layer I can write queries in JPA syntax.

The Problem: I want a list with `Job` and `JobHistory` entries for a given owner with given id and who is the last one in the `Jobhistory` of the job (ordered by assignDate). Sounds quite complicated, perhaps simpler: give me all jobs and `JobHistory` where specified owner is the actual owner of the job.

**Update:** for clarity I will slightly change the names of the classes.

```
class Job 
{
    String description;
    Collection<JobOwnerHistory> history;
}

class JobOwnerHistory
{
    Date assignDate;
    User jobOwner;
}

class JobOwner 
{
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

Every `Job` has a history of his owners sorted by `assignDate`. The actual owner got the job last assigned (i.e. `MAX(assignDate)`). I want find for every job the `JobOwnerHistory` entry with `MAX(assignDate)` for a specific user `User`.

Comment: You need to show the mapping.

Comment: The mapping can be implied from the barebones "entities": Job 0:M JobHistory, User 0:M Job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT j, j.history FROM Job j JOIN User u WHERE u.name = :name
```

If I were to do this in EclipseLink, I would change it slightly:

```
public List<Job> getAllJobsForUser(String username) {
  List<Job> jobs = entityManager
    .createQuery("SELECT j FROM Job j JOIN User u WHERE u.name = :name")
    .setParameter("name", username)
    .setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "j.history")
    .queryForList();
}
```

The difference?  In the first version, you're returning two objects, so you have to retrieve them from a List or Object arrays whereas in the second, the query hint just loads all the job histories from an (assumedly) lazyy one-to-many relationship.

I don't know if Hibernate has an equivalent to this.  Toplink Essentials doesn't.  But it's one of my favourite features of EclipseLink.

Oh and obviously you can (and probably should) use a named query instead of an adhoc query like I've done (since those can be verified during the build).

Comment: I don't know if I understand your answer. I want find the last (newest) entry in the job.history (ordered by assignDate) for every job. Did your solution works this way?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following answer for the query:

```
SELECT j, h FROM Job j JOIN j.history h JOIN h.jobOwner u
WHERE u.name = :name AND 
    (SELECT MAX(h2.assignDate) FROM Job j2 JOIN j2.history h2
     WHERE h2 member of j.history) = h.assignDate
```

The most important part in the query is the subselect with **`MAX(h2.assignDate)`** because I want to get the job and the newest entry in the owner-history.